# How to insert values in an inner arraylist while updating outer arraylist in mongodb?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongotemplate, mongorepository

I am working with Spring MongoDB and now I'm facing a problem for inserting values into an arraylist. Here is my POJO class structure...

```
public class Search implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String searchkey;
    private ArrayList<Lead> leads;
 }
```

"Lead" is another POJO class which is like...

```
public class Lead implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String leadtext;
private String address;
private ArrayList<History> trackrecords;
}
```

"History" is anther POJO class which is like..

```
public class History implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String id;
private String changedfield;
private String oldvalue;
private String newvalue;
}
```

and the problem is i want to insert data into trackrecords while updating one lead. is it possible in spring mongotemplate..?? if it is possible then please help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: What's exactly your query condition for update operation?

Comment: this history is a tracker of editing a lead... if i update anything in a lead class, i have to insert values in that trackrecords. for example if i update leadtext then i have to insert values in trackrecords with values changedfield as leadtext and oldvalue as old leadtext value and new value as new leadtext value.

Comment: You would reach a wider audience by posting the JSON representation of your data rather than your Java classes. But it really seems like you are asking to update the contents of an array inside another, and the documentation should tell you that this cannot be done in most cases. Data and a little more explanation if you still want to try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this.

Suppose `leadtext` can locate that `lead` element uniquely.

```
Query query = new Query().addCriteria(Query.where("searchkey").is(searchkey).and("leads.leadtext").is(leadtext));
Update update = new Update().push("leads.$.trackrecords", trackrecord);
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, Search.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

use mongodb $push to insert or update into an existing arraylist